# How to show this equality using Mobius function?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

Let $n$ be a natural number greater than $1$.

Prove the following:

$$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \sigma(d)=(-1)^rp_1...p_r$$where $p_1,...,p_r$ are the distict prime factors of $n$ and $\mu$ is the Mobius function.

I am really stuck on this problem. The only thing I can think is since $\mu(n)=0$ when $p^2|n$ for some prime $p$ we have a lot of terms in this sum equal to $0$.

Comment: The sum is just $\prod_{p|n} (1+(-1)\times (p+1))$ and the claim follows.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://oeis.org/A062953

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Could you explain why the sum is that and how the claim follows? I spent 10 minutes staring at it and I just can't see unfortunately :(. I don't understand what happens with the $p_ip_j$, $p_ip_jp_k$ etc terms.

Comment: @RyanS See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to complete the question with an answer, see the comments, let me mention that in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82379/how-to-prove-sum-d-mid-n-mudfd-prod-i-1r-1-fp-i?rq=1) it is shown that
$$
\sum_{ d \mid n} \mu(d)f(d)=\prod_{p\mid n} (1-f(p))
$$
for a multiplicative arithmetic function $f$. For $f(n)=\sigma(n)$, the sum of the positive divisors of $n$, we obtain
$$
\sum_{ d \mid n} \mu(d)\sigma(d)=\prod_{p\mid n} (1-\sigma(p))=\prod_{p\mid n}(1-(1+p))=\prod_{p\mid n}(-p).
$$